# CSS override for mobile devices

Tags: css

I have CSS that looks like this:

```
#FSBDiv-Inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

for mobile devices I need to to do this:

```
#FSBDiv-Inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

What do I need to do to the css entry to change values depending on screen resolution?

Comment: Specifically, do you mean resolution or screen width?

Comment: Google CSS media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general, css for limited selectors (such as screen width) is applied via the `@media` rule.**

In your particular example (let's say we only want the rule to apply only to screens with less width than 400px, code would be the following.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {

  #FSBDiv-Inner {
      position: fixed;
      top: 20%;
      width: 100%; 
      z-index: 999;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: white; 
   }

}
```

For further context of the `@media`  rule, I'd absolutely suggest you to check the documentation ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media ) (as there are some important tweaks, as to for example, if the screen is in landscape or potrait position and so on).

Comment: Thanks, read that had to add a bit but worked.

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
    #FSBDiv-Inner {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 20%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: white;
    }
}

Comment: oops apologies, i didn't copy your entire code by accident. Indeed, there should be a separate ID inside your code as well (basically the  `@meida` query acts as it's own stylesheet for all devices that abide the rule. Edited my original post as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to customize the styles according to the devices resolutions, find the link below for more informations:
[Css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is making the page responsive for mobiles too . you can simply use bootstrap for it .Basic container , rows, col-xx-xx will do for it .